# c++ Boost : gregorian_calendar.ipp(77,1): error C2666: '-': 17 overloads have similar conversions in Visual Studio 2019 x64

Tags: c++, boost, 64-bit, visual-studio-2019

i have a strange compilation error when trying to link a simple app with boost and [libunistd](https://github.com/robinrowe/libunistd).
Now both are complied with x64
my linking librarys are :

```
libboost_filesystem-vc142-mt-sgd-x64-1_75.lib
libboost_system-vc142-mt-sgd-x64-1_75.lib
libboost_thread-vc142-mt-sgd-x64-1_75.lib
libunistd.lib
libportable.lib
```

using flags :

```
BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_BUFFER_DEBUGGING 
BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_HANDLER_TRACKING
```

But i keep getting :

```
C:\Dev\my\cpp\libs\boost_1_75_0\boost\date_time\gregorian_calendar.ipp(77,1): error C2666: '-': 17 overloads have similar conversions
1>C:\Dev\my\cpp\libs\libunistd-master\unistd\int128\Int128.h(855,17): message : could be '_uint128 operator -(const _uint128 &,unsigned short)'
1>C:\Dev\my\cpp\libs\libunistd-master\unistd\int128\Int128.h(852,17): message : or       '_uint128 operator -(const _uint128 &,short)'
1>C:\Dev\my\cpp\libs\libunistd-master\unistd\int128\Int128.h(849,17): message : or       '_uint128 operator -(const _uint128 &,unsigned int)'
1>C:\Dev\my\cpp\libs\libunistd-master\unistd\int128\Int128.h(846,17): message : or       '_uint128 operator -(const _uint128 &,int)'
1>C:\Dev\my\cpp\libs\libunistd-master\unistd\int128\Int128.h(843,17): message : or       '_uint128 operator -(const _uint128 &,unsigned long)'
1>C:\Dev\my\cpp\libs\libunistd-master\unistd\int128\Int128.h(840,17): message : or       '_uint128 operator -(const _uint128 &,long)'
1>C:\Dev\my\cpp\libs\libunistd-master\unistd\int128\Int128.h(837,17): message : or       '_uint128 operator -(const _uint128 &,unsigned __int64)'
1>C:\Dev\my\cpp\libs\libunistd-master\unistd\int128\Int128.h(834,17): message : or       '_uint128 operator -(const _uint128 &,__int64)'
1>C:\Dev\my\cpp\libs\libunistd-master\unistd\int128\Int128.h(830,17): message : or       '_int128 operator -(const _int128 &,unsigned short)'
1>C:\Dev\my\cpp\libs\libunistd-master\unistd\int128\Int128.h(827,17): message : or       '_int128 operator -(const _int128 &,short)'
1>C:\Dev\my\cpp\libs\libunistd-master\unistd\int128\Int128.h(824,17): message : or       '_int128 operator -(const _int128 &,unsigned int)'
1>C:\Dev\my\cpp\libs\libunistd-master\unistd\int128\Int128.h(821,17): message : or       '_int128 operator -(const _int128 &,int)'
1>C:\Dev\my\cpp\libs\libunistd-master\unistd\int128\Int128.h(818,17): message : or       '_int128 operator -(const _int128 &,unsigned long)'
1>C:\Dev\my\cpp\libs\libunistd-master\unistd\int128\Int128.h(815,17): message : or       '_int128 operator -(const _int128 &,long)'
1>C:\Dev\my\cpp\libs\libunistd-master\unistd\int128\Int128.h(812,17): message : or       '_int128 operator -(const _int128 &,unsigned __int64)'
1>C:\Dev\my\cpp\libs\libunistd-master\unistd\int128\Int128.h(809,17): message : or       '_int128 operator -(const _int128 &,__int64)'
1>C:\Dev\my\cpp\libs\libunistd-master\unistd\int128\Int128.h(347,17): message : or       '_uint128 operator -(const _uint128 &,const _uint128 &)'
1>C:\Dev\my\cpp\libs\libunistd-master\unistd\int128\Int128.h(342,17): message : or       '_uint128 operator -(const _uint128 &,const _int128 &)'
1>C:\Dev\my\cpp\libs\libunistd-master\unistd\int128\Int128.h(337,16): message : or       '_int128 operator -(const _int128 &,const _uint128 &)'
1>C:\Dev\my\cpp\libs\libunistd-master\unistd\int128\Int128.h(332,16): message : or       '_int128 operator -(const _int128 &,const _int128 &)'
1>C:\Dev\my\cpp\libs\boost_1_75_0\boost\date_time\gregorian\greg_duration.hpp(119,17): message : or       'boost::gregorian::date_duration boost::gregorian::operator -(boost::gregorian::date_duration,const boost::gregorian::date_duration &)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>C:\Dev\my\cpp\libs\boost_1_75_0\boost\date_time\gregorian_calendar.ipp(77,1): message : or       'built-in C++ operator-(int, int)'
1>C:\Dev\my\cpp\libs\boost_1_75_0\boost\date_time\gregorian_calendar.ipp(77,1): message : while trying to match the argument list '(int, const MonthType)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            MonthType=boost::gregorian::greg_month
1>        ]
1>C:\Dev\my\cpp\libs\boost_1_75_0\boost\date_time\gregorian_calendar.ipp(76): message : while compiling class template member function 'unsigned int boost::date_time::gregorian_calendar_base<boost::gregorian::greg_year_month_day,unsigned int>::day_number(const boost::date_time::year_month_day_base<boost::gregorian::greg_year,boost::gregorian::greg_month,boost::gregorian::greg_day> &)'
1>C:\Dev\my\cpp\libs\boost_1_75_0\boost\date_time\date.hpp(75): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'unsigned int boost::date_time::gregorian_calendar_base<boost::gregorian::greg_year_month_day,unsigned int>::day_number(const boost::date_time::year_month_day_base<boost::gregorian::greg_year,boost::gregorian::greg_month,boost::gregorian::greg_day> &)' being compiled
1>C:\Dev\my\cpp\libs\boost_1_75_0\boost\date_time\gregorian\greg_calendar.hpp(28): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::date_time::gregorian_calendar_base<boost::gregorian::greg_year_month_day,unsigned int>' being compiled
```

this is the boost part which it keep fail:

```
template<typename ymd_type_, typename date_int_type_>
  BOOST_CXX14_CONSTEXPR
  inline
  date_int_type_
  gregorian_calendar_base<ymd_type_,date_int_type_>::day_number(const ymd_type& ymd)
  {
    unsigned short a = static_cast<unsigned short>((14-ymd.month)/12);
    unsigned short y = static_cast<unsigned short>(ymd.year + 4800 - a);
    unsigned short m = static_cast<unsigned short>(ymd.month + 12*a - 3);
    unsigned long  d = ymd.day + ((153*m + 2)/5) + 365*y + (y/4) - (y/100) + (y/400) - 32045;
    return static_cast<date_int_type>(d);
  }
```

and this is the [int128](https://github.com/robinrowe/libunistd/blob/master/unistd/int128/Int128.h) that keep failing

Answer (score 0):

Those operators designed with uniformly typed arguments in mind:

`inline _uint128 operator-(const _uint128 &lft, const _int128 &rhs)`

There is also default C++ operator that takes two `int`s. If `ymd.month` is of type `_int128` or is convertible to it, the expression `(14-ymd.month)` is ambiguous because any substitution would require equal number of type conversions.

You have to convert an `int` operand explicitly.

Comment: where to convert as im dealing with 2 open sources libraries